# How can I calculate the sum of all elements within my JList ?

Tags: java, swing, sum, addition

I'm creating a shopping cart simulation with a list of products that i want to add together and display the total of as they are being added to the cart basket (implemented as a jlist).

In my main  class I have a button with an action listener to take items from my stocklist and add them to the basket.

```
scanBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        checkoutBasket.addElement(productList.getSelectedValuesList());
                    }
                });
```

In addition I have a JTextField set up below the basket which I want to dynamically update with the total cost as I add items to the cart. My question is how could I go about doing this ? Thank you.

```
                cartTotalField = new JTextField();
                getContentPane().add(cartTotalField);
                cartTotalField.setBounds(581, 441, 233, 28);
```

Cart Item Class :

```
import java.io.*;

public class CartItem implements Serializable {

    private String barcodeNo;
    private String itemName;
    private String price;

    public CheckoutItem() {

    }

    public CheckoutItem (String barno, String in, String cost) {
            barcodeNo = barno;
            itemName = in;
            price = cost;
    }

    public String getBarcodeNo(){
        return barcodeNo;
    }

    public String getItemName(){
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setitemName(String itemName){
            this.itemName = itemName;
        }

    public String getPrice(){
        return price;
    }


    public String toString(){
        return barcodeNo + ": " + itemName + ", " + price;
    }

    public Object getID() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Loop through all the check out Items in the checkout basket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `actionPerformed`, you could do something like this (of course, this is a very naive approach to get it, you could possibly think of something better on this):

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
  //Get the newly added list values.
  JList list = productList.getSelectedValuesList();
  double totalAddedValue = 0.0;
  double oldCartValue    = 0.0;

  //Iterate to get the price of the new items.
  for (int i = 0; i < list.getModel().getSize(); i++) {
    CartItem item = (CartItem) list.getModel().getElementAt(i);
    totalAddedValue += Double.ParseDouble(item.getPrice());
  }

  //Set total price value as an addition to cart total field.

  //cartTotalField must be accessible here.
  string cartFieldText = cartTotalField.getText();

  //Check that cartTextField already contains a value.
  if(cartTextField != null && !cartTextField.isEmpty())
  {
    oldCartValue = Double.parseDouble(cartFieldText);
  }

  cartTotalField.setText(String.valueOf(oldCartValue  + totalAddedValue));
  checkoutBasket.addElement(list);
}
```

UPDATE: In general, you should consider adding checks and/or exception handling for numeric conversions. A good idea would also be to change the price property to `double` (or `int`, modifying the above code accordingly) in your `CartItem` class.

Comment: Hi Nick! Thank you for your help. Upon trying to add the items I am getting the error - Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String . Any ideas ?

Comment: I guess that the error is coming from the line `double oldCartValue = Double.parseDouble(cartTotalField.getText());` , as you have an empty cartTotalField. You must make checks in order not to call a parse method with a non-properly formatted string. I will update the answer accordingly. Consider voting it as best if you think it is.

Comment: Hi . Thank you very much. Just one more issue, scanning one item into the cart will display the sum total of all items in the inventory list rather than just the one item I'm trying to scan.  It will also print a line under the item name as such `javax.swing.JList[,0,0,344x326,layout=java.awt.BorderLa...` . How could I get around this issue ?

Comment: Hello, I think this issue is a little bit irrelevant with the question above, so I suggest you open a new question with some code along. A quick guess would be that you are not iterating the items correctly, but and again, I can not assume based only on this. Thank you.